# How can I parse HTTP headers in a Chrome extension?

Tags: parsing, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-headers, webrequest

I'm working on a Google Chrome extension that does some processing based on HTTP response headers using the `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived` event. I'm able to receive the headers, but the documentation seems to indicate that the headers are just represented as simple string name-value pairs.

The values for some HTTP headers, particularly `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` in my case, can store multiple pieces of information, including parameters with special mechanisms to escape characters. I want to be able to semantically interpret the header values rather than just see them as strings.

However, I don't want to have to write my own HTTP header value parsing code to meet the HTTP specifications and be able to cope with real-world values; I consider this an entire project of its own, and I want to focus on developing my extension.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Writing your own parser is the only option, there's no built-in method. You could try to Google for existing libraries.

Comment: You should elaborate on why you cannot use `Content-Type` values as strings. What is your end goal with these values?